# Does regex allow you to parse strings? If so, how?

Tags: c#, regex

I've used regex in the past for input validation, but I am wondering if they can let you parse a complex string.

I have a header like this:

```
-----------------------------7dac1d2214d4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"my_title\"\r\n\r\nMyData\r\n-----------------------------7dac1d2214d4\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myupload\"; filename=\"C:\\myfile.zip\"\r\nContent-Type: application/x-zip-compressed\r\n\r\n
```

I want to be able to parse out say, the filename.

At the moment I am doing this (after parsing headers):

```
this.FileName = headers[1].Substring(headers[1].IndexOf("filename=\"") + "filename=\"".Length, headers[1].IndexOf("\"\r\n", headers[1].IndexOf("filename=\"")) - (headers[1].IndexOf("filename=\"") + "filename=\"".Length));
```

But it's hideous and ugly.

Can regex solve this problem more elegently? I understand the basics of the syntax, so if it can solve it, could someone show me how to parse this with regex:

```
"+Name=Bob+Age=39+"
```

I can probably work out the rest myself then.

Thanks.

Comment: Parse into what? What kind of parsing do you need?

Comment: I want to be able to parse out the different properties like filename

Comment: I really think you should have accepted Daniel's answer considering he was first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Named Capturing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) you should be able to parse just about anything and later refer to it by name.

```
var inputString = "+Name=Bob+Age=39+";
var regex = new Regex("Name=(?<Name>[A-Z][a-z]*)\\+Age=(?<Age>[0-9]*)");

var match = regex.Match(inputString);

System.Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", match.Groups["Name"]);
System.Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}", match.Groups["Age"]);

System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Cool, can you explain how you divide the two searches? You are using \\+ does that represent something? Does this regex search care about order?

Comment: The "\\" is just an escape sequence. "+" is a special character in Regex meaning (at least one character). In order to treat it literally I had to escape it. Since "\" indicates an escape sequence in C# strings, I had to escape that with another "\" :) Clear as mud?

Comment: Yes, order is important in this particular Regex. Remember Regex is basically a scanner; much like a compiler uses. There are such things as backtracking, and back references, but for the most part Regular Expression engines scan from left to right.

Comment: Aha I just realised now what's going on. Is there a way to change \\+ into something that says, there might be some random other data in here (such as other properties which we want to ignore)? Is it \S* instead?

Comment: `.*` (or maybe `.*?`) will match everything in between. You have to specify dot-all-mode if there may be newlines.

Answer (score 4):

[Named matched subexpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#named_matched_subexpression) is what best suits your needs. `(?<Name>Expression)` allows you to access the string matching the expression `Expression` via the specified group name `Name`.

```
var input = "Foo=42;Bar='FooBar'";

var regex = new Regex(@"Foo=(?<Foo>[0-9]+);Bar='(?<Bar>[^']+)'");

var match = regex.Match(input);

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Foo"]); // Prints '42'.
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Bar"]); // Prints 'FooBar'.
```

Comment: Curses you beat me to it :) Nice to see a fellow Regex ninja

Comment: I am amazed how similar the two answers are... :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
(?<=filename\=\").*(?=\")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are [Grouping Constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs), which allow you to extract parts of the regex. So using your simplified example:

```
string input = @"+Name=Bob+Age=39+";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Name=(?<Name>[^\+]+)\+Age=(?<Age>[^\+]+)");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name = '{0}'", match.Groups["Name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Age  = '{0}'", match.Groups["Age"]);
}
```